# Beginner Pythonanywhere Query

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

Edit 3:

I am trying to display info from a csv file on pythonanywhere, prompted from a user input into a form.

I have loaded the client_db.csv onto my files on pythonanywhere here:'/home/myusername/mydirectory/client_db.csv'.

Essentially, the user would 'Enter an address: (form)', and values for 'name', 'shack', 'status' and 'payments' would display.

Here is my attempt so far (v3), but I am not getting it to work. I suspect there is something wrong with the html input?

```
from flask import Flask
import os
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["DEBUG"] = True

path = '/home/myusername/ishack'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

client_db = np.genfromtxt('/home/myusername/ishack/client_db.csv', delimiter=',',dtype=None, names=True)

@app.route('/')
def form()
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Enter a Shack Number</h1>

                    <form action="/address" method="POST">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Enter a Shack Number"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """


@app.route('/address', methods=["POST"])
def display_info(address):
    ind = np.where(client_db['Shack']==address)[0]
    return {'Name': client_db['Name'][ind],
            'Shack': client_db['Shack'][ind],
            'Status': client_db['Status'][ind],
            'Payments': client_db['Payments'][ind]}

display_info(address)
```

Comment: So, what have you tried to write with flask? Note, you'll likely want to return data rather than printing it

Comment: incidentally, make sure you use the full path to your csv, so eg */home/myusername/myfolder/things.csv*, not just "things.csv"

Comment: here's a [step-by-step beginners guide to using flask on pythonanwyhere](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121/)

Comment: Thanks for the comments - will go through the step-by-step guide and revert if with an attempt soon.

Comment: @hwjp ok, I went through the tutorial which was very helpful. I've made a (beginners) attempt above...please have a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having minor problems in the code just posted:

- There are minor errors like missing colons and so
- Additionally, note you are indexing wrongly the matrix, putting first the column and later the row, when it is exactly the opposite. The correct sentence is (note ind is before Name for example):

  return {'Name': client_db[ind]['Name'][0],
          'Shack': client_db[ind]['Shack'][0],
          'Status': client_db[ind]['Status'][0],
          'Payments': client_db[ind]['Payments'][0]}
- The last problem is related to the POST of the form. To grab the address data you must use: address = request.form["address"]

For finishing your code, this example returns a JSON data with the fields found in the CSV file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from flask import request
import json
import os
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["DEBUG"] = True

path = '/home/myusername/ishack'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

client_db = np.genfromtxt('/home/myusername/ishack/client_db.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Enter a Shack Number</h1>

                    <form action="/address" method="POST">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Enter a Shack Number"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """


@app.route('/address', methods=["POST"])
def display_info():
    address = request.form["address"]
    ind = np.where(client_db['Shack'] == address)[0]
    res = {'Name': client_db[ind]['Name'][0],
            'Shack': client_db[ind]['Shack'][0],
            'Status': client_db[ind]['Status'][0],
            'Payments': client_db[ind]['Payments'][0]}
    return Response(json.dumps(res), mimetype='application/json')

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Comment: thanks again @maki. I've used your edit, but still no luck. It's difficult to see what's happening, as the url just gives a 'unhandled exception' error constantly. In the least the html code should be displaying something?